# React. Смена класса по клику onClick

Tags: css, reactjs, hook

Не совсем понимаю, почему не работает. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
function Menu() {
    const [Menu__item, setMenu__item] = useState(`Menu__item`)

    function handleClickBtnMenu() {
        setMenu__item(function (prevCount) {
            if (prevCount === `Menu__item`) {
                setMenu__item('Menu__item__active');
            } else if (prevCount === `Menu__item__active`) {
                setMenu__item(`Menu__item`);
            }
        })
    };


    return (
    <div className='Header__menu'>
        <nav className='Menu__body'>
            <ul className='Menu__list'>

                <li className={`${Menu__item}`}> ...}
```

Должен меняться класс у тега `li`, он меняется, но на `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Метод `setMenu__item` - на входе принимает аргумент в качестве функции, либо другое значение. Если Вы используете в качестве первого аргумента функцию, вам необходимо с помощью оператора `return` вернуть значение. В противном случае вы получите `undefined`.

```
function handleClickBtnMenu() {
    setMenu__item(prevCount => {
        if (prevCount === `Menu__item`) {
            return 'Menu__item__active';
        }
        if (prevCount === `Menu__item__active`) {
            return `Menu__item`;
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете callback функцию для изменения значения сосотояния, то данная функция должна вернуть это значение.

Т.к. у вас 2 значения, можно сделать вот так:

```
function handleClickBtnMenu() {
  setMenu__item(prevCount => prevCount === 'Menu__item' ? 'Menu__item__active' : 'Menu__item');
}
```

Или выполнить нужные расчеты за пределами функции изменения состояния и передать уже расчитанное значение:

```
function handleClickBtnMenu() {
  const styleNew = Menu__item === 'Menu__item' ? 'Menu__item__active' : 'Menu__item';
  setMenu__item(styleNew);
}
```